# Proper syntax in configuration files for deploying the Jhipster Registry in a separate VM

Tags: jhipster, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-config, jhipster-registry

I am running the Jhipster Registry on a separate VM and am having trouble with the API connecting. Before the Jhipster Registry was moved to another VM everything was working.

Here are the relevant sections of the configuration files:

application-prod.yml

```
    instance:
        prefer-ip-address: true
    client:
        service-url:
            defaultZone: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@10.202.25.166:8761/eureka/
```

bootstrap-prod.yml

```
    cloud:
        config:
            fail-fast: true
            retry:
                initial-interval: 1000
                max-interval: 2000
                max-attempts: 100
            uri: http://admin:${jhipster.registry.password}@10.202.25.166:8761/config
            name: app
            profile: prod
            label: master
```

I expect that I am setting the URI value incorrectly but am I having trouble finding an example/directions on using an IP vs. "localhost" in the configuration. When the API starts on VM the last output is `"No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added `I added eureka.instance.ip-address: 10.202.25.166` to application-prod.yml and it is now working